# Suitescript sublist using setAmountField

Tags: netsuite, sublist, suitescript

I have a use for using setAmountField in a sublist in Netsuites SuiteScript (1.0).  However, I really am not sure I understand it correctly.  The documentation says "Designates a particular column as the totalling column, which is used to calculate and display a running total for the sublist", which makes sense in that if I had 3 columns, and I wanted to designate column 3 as the running total amount from column 2, I could then set it so by using setAmountField(column2_name).

At least, that's what I thought.  In practice, all I've managed to do is add a column that ends up blank?  Or if I try to programmatically fill it, it ends up as the value of the line or something.

Can someone perhaps give me a small example of how it's supposed to be used so I can dissect it and fix mine / make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I found it to be too restrictive. I assume you are writing a Suitelet, so here goes:

- A much more flexible workaround is to have a field above the Sublist, which is either disabled or inline
- Have a client script which iterates through your sublist with a value has changed, such as a checkbox is checked or unchecked, and then calculate the values yourself
- This same loop can also be used for extended validation for more efficient coding overall, so you could add other validation functions for other columns within the Sublist.

I hope this helps!